# Unable to show View if Database table don't have records

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

This method throws exception when `db.Profits` doesn't have any records. How to prevent explode page

```
public double getProfitSum()
{
   return db.Profits.Where(p => p.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Sum(p => p.Value);
}
```

Error :

> *The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason must be Sum() expects not nullable value. But your result might give null.

try

```
return db.Profits.Where(p => p.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
   && p.Value != null).Select(x=>(double?)x.Value).Sum() ?? 0.0M;
```

Comment: This has various hidden features of c# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c

Answer (score 2):

try that:

```
    var result = db.Profits.Where(p => p.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId).Sum(p => p.Value);

    if(result != null)
      {
          return result;
      }
    return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

or even better

```
    public double getProfitSum()
                {
        var result = db.Profits.Where(p => p.IdUser.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
               && p.Value != null).Sum(p => p.Value);

 return result == null ? 0 : result;
        }
```

Comment: not working  if (result != null) -The result of the expression is always 'true' since a value of type 'double' is never equal to 'null' of type 'double?'

Comment: The cast to value type 'Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type. Same